# How to use LaTeX commands in a luacode* environment?

Tags: lua, luacode

How can one access LaTeX commands in the starred version of `luacode` environment?

I am basically interested in using `\ifdefined` code below.

For example, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
%------------------------
\begin{luacode}
function doItOnlyIf(x,y)   
  \ifdefined\HCode    %will not compile in luacode*
     tex.print(x)
  \else
     tex.print(y)
  \fi
end
\end{luacode}
%-------------------    
\begin{document}    
\directlua{doItOnlyIf("this","that")}
\end{document}
```

But I need to use `luacode*` and not `luacode` (since I have some things that work only in `luacode*` now).

The above only works in the non-starred version of `luacode`.

Compiled with `lualatex foo.tex` and, for `tex4ht`, compiled using `make4ht --lua foo.tex`

Comment: the whole point of luacode is to read the argument verbatim so `\ ` works as it works in lua not as it works in TeX, it is often simpler not to use the package at all and just use `\directlua{function doItOnlyIf(x,y)   
  \ifdefined\HCode    %will not compile in luacode*
     tex.print(x)
  \else
     tex.print(y)
  \fi
end}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've discovered, TeX macros are expanded in a `luacode` environment but not in a `luacode*` environment.

If you need to use a `luacode*` environment, you must check if `\HCode` is defined *outside* the `luacode*` environment, e.g., when calling the Lua function via `\directlua`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function doItOnlyIf(x,y,flag)   
  if flag==1 then   
     tex.print(x)
  else
     tex.print(y)
  end
end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\Hcheck{\ifdefined\HCode1\else0\fi}

\begin{document}    
\directlua{doItOnlyIf( "this", "that", \Hcheck )}
\end{document}
```